# How can you change a picture on the iPhone to make it look comicy or black and white?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, graphics, uiimage

I was wondering, are there any libraries on the iPhone that allow you to take an image and apply some sort of filter to it so the image turns out black and white, or to make it look comicy, or to skew it?

Comment: Use a toonshader when rendering the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out OpenCV. It's an open source library that can be compiled for iOS (there's plenty of tutorials all around the net) and it's specifically made for things like image manipulation.

While it's harder to set up, it's a lot more powerful than CoreImage will be!

There's also plenty of sample code around the net that does things like turn images comicy/black and white/find image outlines/thresholds images etc. There's a small learning curve, but for what you want to do, it's more than worth it :)

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking a look at CoreImage.  Its available in iOS5.  You'll probably want to explore third party options too.